# Ввод текста в input и вывод в несколько output. html ,css

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня получается вывести текст из input в output если output находится в теге p, но если output находится в div ничего не выводится. Как сделать так, чтобы из input я мог вывести в любом месте например ссылаясь на id или что-то похожее.

```css
.block2{
    min-height: 200px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #1E589F;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.block1{
    min-height: 70px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="text" placeholder="Введи текст"></p>

<div class="block1">
  <div class="block2">
    <output></output>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block1">
  <div class="block2">
    <output></output>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш JS код

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    let form = document.querySelector("#form");
        form.text.addEventListener("input", function() {
          let out = form.result;

          for (let i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
            out[i].textContent = form.text.value;
          }
        });
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let form = document.querySelector("#form"); 

const output = document.querySelectorAll("output");

form.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
  
  for(const out of output)
    out.innerHTML = form.value;
});
```

[Полный код](https://codepen.io/nixxwins/pen/ZEBgwbz)
Ваш js код не полный. Написал чуть по другому.

Comment: Спасибо, ставлю галочку !